# C Doubly Circular Linked List Deletion

Tags: c, list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list, function-definition

I'm having a problem deleting from a circular doubly linked list. I have tried various different methods mentioned here, but they all cause some sort of error. Here, I'm getting an error saying "double free detected in tcache 2"

```
void delete_list(Node *node)
{
        Node *pt;
        while(node != NULL){
                pt = node;
                node = node->next;
                free(pt);
        }
}
```

Comment: @ProudFrog1337 Provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] but the problem is obvious: you have a circular list and you're checking for a NULL that doesn't exist and eventually `node` loops back to previously free'd memory. Set the `node->prev->next` pointer to NULL, then run your traversal.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm having a problem deleting from **a circular doubly linked list**

A **circular** doubly linked list does not have a node with the data member `next` that is equal to `NULL`. The `tail` node in its data member `next` has the address of the `head` node.

So if your list is not empty then this function

```
void delete_list(Node *node)
{
        Node *pt;
        while(node != NULL){
                pt = node;
                node = node->next;
                free(pt);
        }
}
```

invokes undefined behavior after it moves from the `tail` node to the `head` node that it tries to free twice.

The function can look for example the following way (without testing)

```
void delete_list( Node **head )
{
    if ( *head )
    {
        Node *current = ( *head )->next;
     
        while ( current != *head )
        {
            Mode *tmp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free( tmp );
        }

        free( *head );
        *head = NULL;
    }
}
```

If in main you have a declaration like

```
Node *head = NULL;
//...
```

then the function can be called like

```
delete_list( &head );
```

Pay attention to that the function does not deal with the pointer to the tail node if it is declared separately apart from the pointer to the head node.

In this case you need to introduce one more structure as for example

```
struct CircularList
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};
```

that indeed defines a list. And call the (modified) function for an object of this type.

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood the idea of what free does. I thought it would automatically set the freed value to null. I tried again by adding "node->previous->next = NULL" and am now getting a segmentation fault. I suppose that error is from somewhere else?

Comment: @ProudFrog1337 I think it is an invalid approach. Insert a test output of values stored in nodes that are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

free'ing a node in a doubly linked list does NOT remove that node from the list.

The code must correct the 'next' field of the prior node in the list and correct the 'prev' field of next node in the list so those fields skip the node to be deleted, Then the node to be deleted can be passed to `free()`

Answer (score 0):

```
void delete_list(Node **head){
        Node *current, *garbage;

        if (*head==NULL) return; else current=(*head)->next;

        while(current != *head){
                garbage=current;
                current = current->next;
                free(garbage);
        }

        free(current);
        *head=NULL;
}
```

Comment: `node->prev->next=NULL;` risks `node->prev->next` being `NULL`.